# Query multiple tables and have results updated in another database table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query (MySQL) which pulls data from 4 tables within the same database.  What I would like to do is have the query run and have the results be either updated if there was a change and have new records be inserted into a separate table in another database.

```
SELECT a.Created,
a.id 'TicketID',
GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN d.CustomField = 1 THEN d.Content ELSE NULL END)) `CompanyName`,
a.Subject,
c.Name Queue,
b.Name 'Owner',
a.`Status`,
a.LastUpdated,
GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN d.CustomField = 4 THEN d.Content ELSE NULL END)) `Location`,
a.TimeWorked 'TimeWorked',
GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN d.CustomField = 2 THEN d.Content ELSE NULL END)) `OverRide`,
a.Resolved
FROM    rt.Tickets a
    INNER JOIN rt.Users b
        ON a.owner = b.id
    INNER JOIN rt.Queues c
        ON a.queue = c.id
    INNER JOIN  rt.ObjectCustomFieldValues d
        ON a.id = d.ObjectID
GROUP BY a.id
```

The above query is pulls data from our ticketing system.

I was able to initally insert the data using the following:

```
INSERT INTO Support (Created, TicketID, CompanyName, Subject, Queue, Owner, Status, LastUpdated, Location, Timeworked, OverRide, Resolved)
SELECT a.Created,
a.id 'TicketID',
GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN d.CustomField = 1 THEN d.Content ELSE NULL END)) `CompanyName`,
a.Subject,
c.Name Queue,
b.Name 'Owner',
a.`Status`,
a.LastUpdated,
GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN d.CustomField = 4 THEN d.Content ELSE NULL END)) `Location`,
a.TimeWorked 'TimeWorked',
GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN d.CustomField = 2 THEN d.Content ELSE NULL END)) `OverRide`,
a.Resolved
FROM    rt.Tickets a
    INNER JOIN rt.Users b
        ON a.owner = b.id
    INNER JOIN rt.Queues c
        ON a.queue = c.id
    INNER JOIN  rt.ObjectCustomFieldValues d
        ON a.id = d.ObjectID
GROUP BY a.id
```

However when trying to update the data that is already there or adding additional new data I get errors.

```
UPDATE Support
SELECT a.Created,
a.id 'TicketID',
GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN d.CustomField = 1 THEN d.Content ELSE NULL END)) `CompanyName`,
a.Subject,
c.Name Queue,
b.Name 'Owner',
a.`Status`,
a.LastUpdated,
GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN d.CustomField = 4 THEN d.Content ELSE NULL END)) `Location`,
a.TimeWorked 'TimeWorked',
GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN d.CustomField = 2 THEN d.Content ELSE NULL END)) `OverRide`,
a.Resolved
FROM    rt.Tickets a
    INNER JOIN rt.Users b
        ON a.owner = b.id
    INNER JOIN rt.Queues c
        ON a.queue = c.id
    INNER JOIN  rt.ObjectCustomFieldValues d
        ON a.id = d.ObjectID
GROUP BY a.id
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried a stored procedure or a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the user you are using has proper permissions in both, you can do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO destination_database.table_name
(SELECT source_database.source_table.field_name
FROM source_database.source_table);
```

In your case your destination table must have 11 fields that you are selecting, with comparable data types.

Comment: As I said in the post that I was initially able to use the INSERT INTO to populate the data in the table. What I now need to be able to do is to UPDATE the table. If I run INSERT INTO that will just duplicate the data.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to define a view, rather than manually manage the 'derived table' yourself. Then the database can just reflect the changes in your source tables as they are made.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp